# How to pass onchange actionFunction's new value to oncomplete event JS?

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript

Below is the sample code(I wrote it randomly). oncomplete of the actionfunction, javascript is being called, but the picklist value is being "undefined". I even tried $component.id, but the picklist value is still being "undefined". Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

```
<apex:form id="the form">
<apex:pageblocksectionItem>
 <apex:outputlabel> hi </apex:outputlabel>
  <apex:actionregion>
    <apex:inputfield value="{!picklist}" onchange="change();"/>
  </apex:actionregion>
</apex:pageblocksectionItem>

<apex:actionfunction name="change" action={!apexmethod} rerender="theForm" oncomplete"callscript()" />

</apex:form>

<script>
 function script()
{
if(picklist == 'yes')
{
  alert ('random info');
}
}
</script>
```

Comment: hmm where to begin.. there are so many issues in the code..syntax wise & usage as well.. what exactly is your requirement ?

Answer (score 1):

To start, you need to reference the field via a selector or id

Lots of stuff to say, but this should solve your immediate issue

```
<apex:form id="the form">
<apex:pageblocksectionItem>
 <apex:outputlabel> hi </apex:outputlabel>
  <apex:actionregion>
    <apex:input field id="thefield" value="{!picklist}" onchange="change();"/>
  </apex:actionregion>
</apex:pageblocksectionItem>

<apex:actionfunction name="change" action={!apexmethod} rerender="theForm" oncomplete"callscript()" />

</apex:form>

<script>
 function script()
{
if(document.getElementById('{!$Component.thefield}').value == 'yes')
{
  alert ('random info');
}
}
</script>
```